# Blender Python cache addon property data

Tags: python, scripting, add-on

I have a script with a UI panel.  In the UI panel there is an `bpy.props.EnumProperty` select dropdown.

I want to populate this Enum with data downloaded from an API.  However I don't want the user to have to re-download the data every time they start up Blender.

I've tried putting the data into an addon preference field, but the problem is that the Props seem to get loaded before the addon preferences (so I can't get the cached data from the preference field to load it into the prop).

Is there some other way I can cache the data for my `EnumProperty` to prevent multiple downloads?

Comment: Hello, could you post a bit of your code and the way you handle things currently ?